# How do you stop a view shadow from reaching into another view controller on its side?

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, shadow

[image: middle of two view controllers where shadow shows seam]

[image: middle of two other view controllers where shadow shows again]

I want this white title bar to be seamless between three view controllers, but the shadow of the bar shows where the view controllers end and start.

***Styling for the white bar on all three view controllers:***

```
navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 3
```

I have already tried insetting the shadow on each side, and while that hides the shadow on the side, it also erases some of the shadow on the bottom of the white bar.

My goal is to have a continuous white bar through all three view controllers with a shadow with offset height: 3

Comment: Did you try applying a custom `shadowPath`?

Comment: @matt I did try adding a separate shadow path with x insets on either side, and it made a gap on the bottom shadow.

Comment: What is `navigationBar` in your case and how you inject views in it? Applying shadow to layer of parent view should not affect subviews.

Comment: @Asperi It is simply a view that stretched from edge to edge with a white background and a title and buttons on it. Im not sure what you mean by it affecting subviews. My issue is the shadow that I only want on the bottom, shows on the sides and reveals where the two view controllers split when you swipe from each UIPageViewController.

Comment: Then I assume you applies shadow not to that view, apply it to super view of those page controllers.